# C# Julian Date Parser

Tags: c#, .net, julian-date

I have a cell in a spreadsheet that is a date object in Excel but becomes a double (something like 39820.0 for 1/7/2009) when it comes out of C1's xls class.  I read this is a Julian date format.  Can someone tell me how to parse it back into a DateTime in C#?

Update: It looks like I might not have a Julian date, but instead the number of days since Dec 30, 1899.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think Excel is just using the standard OLE Automation [DATE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc237601.aspx) type which can be converted with the `DateTime.FromOADate` method.

This block of code,

```
using System;

namespace DateFromDouble
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.FromOADate(39820.0));
        }
    }
}
```

outputs:

```
1/7/2009 12:00:00 AM
```

Answer (score 9):

There's a JulianCalendar class in System.Globalization; Here's how you would use it:

```
            JulianCalendar c = new JulianCalendar();
            DateTime time = c.ToDateTime(2009, 1, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0);
            Console.WriteLine(time.ToShortDateString());
```

EDIT:

If it is in fact days since "1900" here's how you can do it:

```
public static DateTime DaysSince1900(int days)
{
    return new DateTime(1900, 1, 1).AddDays(days);
}



 DateTime time = DaysSince1900(39820);
 Console.WriteLine(time.ToShortDateString()); //will result in "1/9/2009"
```

Comment: Looks like a good candidate for an extension method: DateTime.Since1900(...)

Comment: Your function returns 1/9/2009 for 39820, but the question says 39820 is 1/7/2009. It probably really is the number of days since 12/30/1899, so you'd want to use DateTime(1899,12,30), or use GBegen's answer

Comment: Here is a link to more information about System.Globalization's JulianCalendar class...  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.juliancalendar.aspx

Comment: this difference of one day is a well-known and very nasty bug specific to Excel, that's on the will-not-fix list for backwards compatibility reasons. when you're parsing an excel date in this way, you need to AddDays(-1)

Answer (score 2):

That number looks like a 'number of days since 1900' value.

Comment: I think you might be right, what is the proper way to parse that?

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to do this CONVERSION --

1. OLE Automation Date method --

   ```
   double doubleDate = 43153.0;
   DateTime normalDate = DateTime.FromOADate(doubleDate);
   /* {2/22/2018 12:00:00 AM} */
   ```
2. DateAdd() Method, using this method, you can specify the kind of date to convert to

   ```
   double doubleDate = 43153.0;
   DateTime normalDate = new DateTime(1899, 12, 30, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc).AddDays(doubleDate);
   /* {2/22/2018 12:00:00 AM} */
   ```

Note:  This date constant {12h December 31, 1899} is called the Dublin Julian Day documented in [Julian Day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day)

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with Excel dates, the date may be the string representation of a date, or it may be an OA date. This is an extension method I wrote a while back to help facilitate the date conversion:

```
/// <summary>
/// Sometimes the date from Excel is a string, other times it is an OA Date:
/// Excel stores date values as a Double representing the number of days from January 1, 1900.
/// Need to use the FromOADate method which takes a Double and converts to a Date.
/// OA = OLE Automation compatible.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="date">a string to parse into a date</param>
/// <returns>a DateTime value; if the string could not be parsed, returns DateTime.MinValue</returns>
public static DateTime ParseExcelDate( this string date )
{
    DateTime dt;
    if( DateTime.TryParse( date, out dt ) )
    {
        return dt;
    }

    double oaDate;
    if( double.TryParse( date, out oaDate ) )
    {
        return DateTime.FromOADate( oaDate );
    }

    return DateTime.MinValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just format the cell(s) in question as Date, use CTRL+1, and select the your desired format.